# C++ Threaded Stopwatch

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, stopwatch

I am trying to create a stopwatch in C++, something similar to Java's [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). I like their library since it already has threading built in. I have seen [Boost Chrono](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/chrono/libs/chrono/doc/html/index.html), however, it's still in development and would prefer not to use it.

My current implementation has been without luck (I am going by memory right now so this might be a little pseudo code like).

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io);


Initialize()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(
      new boost::thread(
        boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)
  );
}

Start()
{
   timer.async_wait(
       bind(&HandleTimerEvent, this, asio::placeholders::error)
   );
}

Stop()
{
  timer.cancel
}

Tick()
{
   cout << "THE TIME IS: " << timer.current_time << endl; // Pseudo code for current_time.
}

HandleTimerEvent(boost::system::error_code& e)
{
  cout << "Timer has ended: " << e << endl;
}
```

What I would like to have is to have the thread continuously call `Tick()` and print out the current time. Also, my current implementation seems to have the thread as blocking the rest of the application which is something I definitely don't want. How would I do both of these things?

I am a noob when it comes to threading so please forgive me if I stated something that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly have it, because you're creating a new thread to handle `io_service::run()`, your main thread will not block. Two things you need to do,

1. ensure you call `Start()` before you `Initialize()` (using the same io_service instance), this way there is something for the io_service to do, else it will quit!
2. On your `HandleTimer()` method, call `async_wait` again to queue up the next tick, else io_service will quit as it has nothing to do..

Comment: Your second point was one of those slap-the-forehead moments. But it works great now. Thank you.

Comment: :) cool, the whole scheduling of events it's tricky to get to grips with, took me a while too...

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Boost.Asio asynchronous [deadline timer tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html)? It's fairly trivial to add [multiple threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) by creating a thread pool to invoke `io_service::run`.

> Multiple threads may call
>   io_service::run() to set up a pool of
>   threads from which completion handlers
>   may be invoked. This approach may also
>   be used with io_service::post() to use
>   a means to perform any computational
>   tasks across a thread pool.
>
> Note that all threads that have joined
>   an io_service's pool are considered
>   equivalent, and the io_service may
>   distribute work across them in an
>   arbitrary fashion.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

static struct timeval tv_s, tv_e;

static void timer_start()
{
   gettimeofday( &tv_s, NULL );
}

static unsigned long timer_stop()
{
   gettimeofday( &tv_e, NULL );
   return (tv_e.tv_sec - tv_s.tv_sec ) * 1000000ul
      + ( tv_e.tv_usec - tv_s.tv_usec );
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a threaded stopwatch so I can consistently call `Tick`. This implementation doesn't really help me.

Comment: This is tagged C++.  `static` is hardly thread-safe in any case.  Expect downvotes.

Comment: If all you need is to time an operation (a "stopwatch") this is a better solution by every metric. If you want to mimic TimerTask then it's not a stopwatch. Excuse me for trying to suggest a better solution.